# Play specs with configuration break because "There is no started application"

Tags: configuration, playframework-2.0, specs2

I externalized some strings to HOCON, on `application.conf`. I'm accessing the configuration values like this:

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.Play.configuration

configuration.getString("foo.bar").get()
```

As early as possible, to fail fast in case of a missing key, like the docs say.

Now some of my tests that depend on *configured* objects are failing with a stacktrace that states:

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`

I assume this has to do with the configuration? How can I fix this? (tests are [specs2](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/))

Answer (score 9):

Do you have a `FakeApplication` running? As stated in the documents: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaTest before you run the test/ test method?

Example from the Wiki:

```
@Test
public void findById() {
   running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Computer macintosh = Computer.find.byId(21l);
        assertThat(macintosh.name).isEqualTo("Macintosh");
        assertThat(formatted(macintosh.introduced)).isEqualTo("1984-01-24");
       }
   });
}
```

If this is not solving your issue, perhaps providing more information from the Stacktrace would help.

EDIT: Please tag your question carefully, it does not make sense to mention `playframework` AND `playframework-2.0`

Comment: So, I need to have **every single test** wrapped in that block just to use some config values? There must be an easier/non-hack way

Comment: That is a good question :) Perhaps creating a Singleton class and initialize at when you start your testcases... I cannot come up with something else right now

Comment: To be fair, that's the solution I'm actually using, I just thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: If you are using specs2, you can a context [implicitly](https://gist.github.com/2879222#file_unit_tests2.scala)